# How to change option value with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I am looking for a way to change the option value from a select tag when users click on a link.

For example I have a select option html:

```
<select> <option value="0">Please Select</option> 
<option value="1">red</option> 
<option value="2">white</option> 
</select>
```

And I have 2 links `<a href="#" title="red" class="preview_link">red</a> <a href="#" title="white">white</a>`
When user clicks red the option will switch to red and white will switch to white. I am using the following code but it is not working.

```
 jQuery("a.preview_link").click(function() {
    var title = jQuery(this).attr("title");
        jQuery(this).parent('p').children("select :selected").text(title);
 });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Also why not use $ instead of typing out jQuery ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your way will set the option's text to the title attribute. Try:

```
 jQuery("a.preview_link").click(function() {
    var title = jQuery(this).attr("title");
    jQuery(this).parent('p').find("select option").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == title;
    }).attr('selected', 'selected');
 });
```

See [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: Are you selecting the `select` correctly? Try `alert(jQuery(this).parent('p').find("select option").length);` within your event handler.

Comment: So that's working. My last thought is, in your post, the markup for one of your options is missing a double quote on the value attribute: `<option value=2">` should be `<option value="2">`. Try fixing that? Also, I noticed that you are using `children`, which I edited to `find` in my answer (but I'm not sure that makes any difference).

Comment: @Rick: In your code example you've the `class="preview_link"` set in only the first link. This should be on all links. Karim's code by the way works fine. [Here's a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yr2Ne/).

Comment: yes it is on all links...just missed typed it here...Let me dig further to see what is going on...Thanks guys for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you're going about this wrong: Instead of changing the text of the selected option you need to loop over the `<option/>` elements and select the appropriate one, something like this:

```
$("select option").each(function() { 
    if($(this).text() == "red")) {
        this.selected = true; 
    }
});
```

Edit: There might be a `select()` function in jQuery. If that's the case then use that over the DOM property.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
$("select #some-option").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Or this?

```
$("select").val(index);
```