# Change value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the value from a drop-down list via jQuery.

```
<option value="Yes" data-select2-id="248">Yes</option>
```

In this instance I want to change the `value="Yes"` to `value="15"`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change option value with Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269030/how-to-change-option-value-with-jquery)

Comment: Also if you google "jquery change option value" or something like that you will likely find an answer very quickly.

Comment: And any one of the following questions on StackOverflow could be easily modified to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736539/jquery-change-option-value-after-selection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231968/jquery-jqplot-change-option-value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617609/change-option-value-based-on-its-current-value-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Use `.val()`

```
$(<identifier>).val("15");
```

Here is some reference: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: If you find a question likely to be a duplicate like this one, please notify the OP in the comments and flag as duplicate.

Comment: This does not work. I need to find the option by text and then change the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "option" ).data( "select2-id", 15 );
```

Comment: If you find a question likely to be a duplicate like this one, please notify the OP in the comments and flag as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did with the select2 plugin.

It finds the text of the option and changes the vaule.

```
$('#Contact').find("option:contains(" + data.FullName +")").attr('value', data.Id).trigger('change');
```